# In Drupal, after installing responsive menu, page content is missing

Tags: php, drupal-7

After installing responsive menu:

[image: Responsive menu - mean menu]

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-user page-user- page-user-1517 fc-save-form-session-processed" style="">
```

is blocking the page content. Please help me out of these.

Comment: probably you've miss some configuration in your admin panel.

Comment: yes. can you suggest me. if i log in as admin, i am able to see the content

Comment: <body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-user page-user- page-user-1517 fc-save-form-session-processed" style="">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an answer, though it might be partial:

Have you tried the Responsive Menu in a default Bartnik theme to see if the problem still exists? There's a chance that your current theme is designed in a way that Responsive Menu does not take into account. I've had that happen on a few sites in the past, and adjusting the theme itself was the solution.

Comment: your response helped me. I tried Responsive Menu in a default Bartnik theme. There its perfect. Are there any other modules, custom modules to make mobile menu in drupal 7?

Comment: There are two projects for responsive menus I'm familiar with:  

Responsive Menu: https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menu (about 5k users)  

Responsive Menus: https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus (about 50k users)  

If neither works, I really recommend looking into patching your theme. There's a good chance that if neither of the two projects works with it, visitors to your site might experience other CSS problems you're not yet aware of...